# VBA 1004 Error on Loop execution of Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Can anybody give me a sense of why I'd be receiving a 1004 error on the following code?

If it's not clear, I'm trying to loop all sheets that are not my named sheet and try to select a particular range and copy and paste it to the compiled "Quant Sheet"

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer 
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Quant Sheet")
x = 1
y = 3
a = 3
b = 2

Worksheets("Quant Sheet").Activate
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If (ws.Name <> "Quant Sheet") Then

   ws.Range("A3").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Quant Sheet").Select
   Cells(y, 1).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   y = y + 1


End If

Next ws
```

Comment: You cannot select a cell until you activate its parent worksheet. Use `ws.activate` before `AB$2:AE" & lastRowSF`. Once it's working take a look at [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `WS` as `Worksheets("Quant Sheet")` but then use that same variable `ws` to use in your loop.  That may be causing the issue.

Try this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, mainWS As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer
Set mainWS = Worksheets("Quant Sheet")
x = 1
y = 3
a = 3
b = 2

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If (ws.Name <> "Quant Sheet") Then
   ws.Range("A3").Copy Destination:=mainWS.Cells(y, 1)
   y = y + 1
End If

Next ws
```

Mainly, you want to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/) to make sure you work more directly with the data.

Edit: FYI you can likely further make this more dynamic by not using something like `y=y+1` and instead use offset, or a `lastRow` variable, but that's personal preference as it'll accomplish the same thing.   (I'm also assuming the `x`, `a`, and `b` variables are used elsewhere in your macro...

Comment: `ws.Range("A3").Copy Destination:=mainWS.Cells(y, 1)` .Paste is a worksheet method, not a range method.

Comment: @Jeeped - D'oh, thanks for fixing that, I just noticed it too.

Comment: Well, I couldn't upvote you in the original form and I promised my dog a cheeseburger so I have to be going.

Comment: @Jeeped - Wait ...I thought you *were* the dog!

Comment: @jeeped I think I'm running into that problem again. however because I need a special paste (transpose) I don't know how to deal with it. See my updated code and please feel free to show me the light if you would be so kind!

Comment: That is a new question. Reverse your edit and create a new question. In the new question, specify if you require values only or values and formats. You cannot transpose formulas without invoking #REF! errors. Besides, what's wrong with Batman? (oops!)

Answer (score 3):

[As was already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946514/vba-1004-error-on-loop-execution-of-macro/43946661#comment74926003_43946514), you can't `.Select` a cell on a worksheet you haven't called `.Activate` on first - that *would* fix the problem, but leave you with frail & slow `.Select` and `.Activate` calls everywhere. Instead, iterate the `Worksheets` collection with a `For Each` loop, so you get a `Worksheet` object to work with each iteration:

```
Sub test()
    Dim quantSheet As Worksheet, tempSheet as Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set quantSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quant Sheet")
    i = 3

    For Each tempSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If tempSheet.Name <> quantSheet.Name Then
            quantSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = tempSheet.Range("A3").Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next tempSheet
End Sub
```

---

Further to the good answers and comments already provided, you can neaten up your code a lot.

- Indentation is **key**. You can avoid loads of errors just by sticking to simple indentation
- Remove of all those unused variables (unless you're using them later and haven't shown us!)
- Rather than copying and pasting, set your values directly using `.Value`. It's quicker and better
- Avoid `Select` and `Activate` as much as possible, as has already been pointed out. That includes `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook`
- Give your variables good, meaningful names and your code will almost read like a geeky VBA novel. That way you'll always know what's going on.

Post your working code on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for a full-blown peer review.

Comment: I realize I have a lot of cleaning up to do!